# dplyr "data_frame" function could not do recycling and data.frame has limitation?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Having packages loaded as below:

```
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.3 dplyr_0.3       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] assertthat_0.1 DBI_0.3.1      magrittr_1.0.1 parallel_3.1.1 plyr_1.8.1     Rcpp_0.11.2   
[7] reshape2_1.4   stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.1.1
```

Trying to experiment the interesting "data_frame" function in the new dplyr_0.3. Seems data_frame could not do recycling when building a data frame.  Is this intentional?

```
data_frame(x=letters[1:10], y=1:5, z=runif(10))  ## pay attention to "y" column
Error in data_frame_(lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 10, 5, 10
```

whereas, the base data.frame function could achieve that...

```
data.frame(x=letters[1:10], y=1:5, z =runif(10))
   x y          z
1  a 1 0.54345855
2  b 2 0.98478537
3  c 3 0.51510861
4  d 4 0.03766893
5  e 5 0.32097472
6  f 1 0.77391366
7  g 2 0.61993720
8  h 3 0.87983035
9  i 4 0.63159025
10 j 5 0.53198094
```

though data.frame will give an error if the multiple of number of rows of the intended data frame over the number of elements in "y" column is not an integer:

```
data.frame(x = letters[1:10], y = 1:4, z = runif(10))  ## Note the change on "y"
Error in data.frame(x = letters[1:10], y = 1:4, z = runif(10)) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 10, 4
```

Seems only data.table could attempt to complete the task with warning message given:

```
data.table(x = letters[1:10], y = 1:4, z = runif(10))
    x y          z
 1: a 1 0.17149580
 2: b 2 0.56452774
 3: c 3 0.01237395
 4: d 4 0.47183540
 5: e 1 0.52561037
 6: f 2 0.27053798
 7: g 3 0.82603959
 8: h 4 0.73871563
 9: i 1 0.03931619
10: j 2 0.34125535
Warning message:
In data.table(x = letters[1:10], y = 1:4, z = runif(10)) :
  Item 2 is of size 4 but maximum size is 10 (recycled leaving remainder of 2 items)
```

Why such different behaviours working with "data_frame" and "data.frame"?
I am working with dataframes and datatables simultaneously with dplyr and data.table packages.  Understanding the behaviour would help avoid pricey errors.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: "Is this intentional?". Well, from the help text of `data_frame`: "Only recycles length 1 inputs.". So yes, I assume it is intentional.

Q: "Why?": Probably because `data_frame` is a "trimmed down version of data.frame" (from `?data_frame`).

Comment: And because this sort of recycling is a common source of errors.